# Write arbitrary POST data to socket with fixed size buffer

Tags: python, sockets, buffer, micropython

Foreword: the code below is micropython and works on a microcontroller, the question is per se, I guess, platform independent and related to how sockets work, which I'm really new.

In an application I send data from i2c eeprom to a server using a socket.

```
import usocket

buf = bytearray(64)
#...
socket = usocket.socket(*addrinfo[:3])
socket.connect(addrinfo[-1])
#...
socket.write('{0} /{1} HTTP/1.0\r\n'.format(method, path))
socket.write('Host: {0}\r\n'.format(host))
socket.write(b'Content-Length: {0}\r\n'.format(eeprom.payload_size))
socket.write('\r\n')
#... fill buf with eeprom data...
socket.write(buf)
```

This works for small amounts of data.

Problem is data can exceed 64 bytes -- the eeprom is 8kbytes and teoretically I could have the need to send thm all -- and I would like to write all data to the same socket reusing the same buffer over and over.

I tried with an iterator, only the first buffer is sent, following socket.write are lost

```
def ipayload(self, buf):
    size = len(buf)
    for memaddr in range(self.__head_pointer, self.__tail_pointer, size):
        self.read_into(memaddr, buf)
        yield min(self.__tail_pointer - memaddr, size)

#...
for c in eeprom.ipayload(buf):
    socket.write(buf)
```

Server side I use PHP and read the whole input stream (I guess):

```
$content_lenght = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
$input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
while (!feof($input) && $data = fread($input, 8)){
    $content_lenght -= 8
    //use data
}
```

Also a check on `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` and `$content_lenght` shows I always get 64 bytes, so the first buffer only.

How can I do? Currently I let python allocate memory for a new bytestring every time I read from eeprom, risking I overflow in case it's the full 4Kb to be sent.

Comment: I'm not sure what your are trying to do here. It looks like you are trying to send a HTTP request with a body. But your request is missing the `content-length` header to tell the server up-front how many body data to expect. Maybe this will result in the *"following socket.write are lost"* you see (you don't explain how exactly you check for this loss).

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the content-length, I will add it along with server side code

Comment: @SteffenUllrich added, I hope it gives a better understanding

Comment: *"... a check on `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` and `$content_lenght` shows I always get 64 bytes"* - If I understand this correctly your server explicitly sends a `Content-length: 64`, i.e. the `eeprom.payload_size` does not specify the size of the full payload you actually want to sent. Of course you need to send the correct size of the full payload.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm sure because I log it that the microcontroller sends `socket.write(b'Content-Length: 152\r\n'` in the header and the server gets `152` in `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` however the `while (!feof($input) && $data = fread($input, 8))` PHP loop exits after 64 bytes read. Any clue?

Comment: Are you sure that the the multiple writes actually gets issued? As you can see from your previous writes to send the HTTP header - multiple writes simply don't get lost. This is no general issue with they way you do sockets either.